# NGINX/haproxy resets websockets connections on adding machine

Tags: nginx, haproxy

How can I add machine instances to a running `nginx` and `haproxy`?

Will that cause resetting (client `A` will not point to the same server) the existing `wss` websockets SSL connections.

Can this resetting be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

You just change nginx configuration an send the signal:

```
/usr/bin/nginx -s reload
```

Nginx will start the new worker processes with a new configuration and gracefully shutdown the old worker processes.

Comment: can i avoid restarting nginx server and a node

Comment: I don't know the simple way to avoid restarting server. Web socket clients should take into consideration that network or server can disappear. Anyway graceful shutdown means old workers should stay alive and process all old connections before quit.